# Firefox buttons have padding, Chrome buttons do not

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

How do I get my `<button>`s to look consistent in Firefox and Chrome? Is there a **non-conditional** CSS solution? Right now, Firefox's buttons have extra padding even though [YUI's CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) made the padding 0.

[image: HTML button]

I discovered that to get the same appearance, Chrome needs to have double the padding.

```
            #fileActions button {
                padding: 0.2em;
            }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
            #fileActions button {
                padding: 0.4em;
            }
}
```

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome computed style]

**Firefox**

[image: firefox computed style]

Comment: I also have never been able to remove all the padding from Firefox buttons. Just an example of what I have run in to is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2BMK/. IE8, Chrome work correctly. Firefox adds mysterious padding. I would use a tags instead of buttons but I don't like the way a tags can be dragged and also a tags do not automatically trigger on space bar when focused.

Comment: I try to stay away from `<a>` for things that trigger javascript. **(1)** It's not semantically correct. `<a>` is supposed to go to a new URL. **(2)** There's extra code for an `<a>` to simulate a `<button>`: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="func(); return false;">` VS `<button onclick="func()">`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove extra button spacing/padding in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox gives buttons something called inner focus, this allows it to draw the dotted focus line. There is a rule in `forms.css` for it, which gives it 1px of border and 2px of left and right padding. I don't know whether it's possible to override this from a web page.

Comment: It is. The only drawback is that it will not get a dotted line when focused. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox/5518143#5518143

Comment: @George Bailey Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It´s hard to say without seeing your css, but if you check the css of the YUI reset, you will see that it does not set or reset any properties for the `button` element except for the inherited ones and that does not include padding as far as I know.

Comment: My CSS is *cascaded* across several *sheets* and several locations, so I thought it would be easier to provide the computed styles. Isn't this all that matters? Both the computed styles on FF and C show that padding is 0.

Comment: @JoJo I´ve never had this problem before, do you have a live example?

Comment: It's a little bit hard to show because our website requires a video player plugin to function, but I have a workaround. Go to http://www.veetle.com. Then open up your console (Firebug) to append a new button to the very bottom of the page: `$$('body').first().appendChild((new Element('button')).update('button'));`. You'll see that the button has extra padding in FF.

Comment: @JoJo Very strange, I´ve never run into that before but you're right `padding:0` does not remove all padding in Firefox. No idea how to solve that one...

Comment: That's why I prefer to use `<a>` instead of `<button>` in most situations, even though `<button>` is semantically correct for triggering javascript that doesn't go to a new page. I've also found that some attributes of `<button>` is not styleable in IE6.

Comment: @JoJo Don't get me started on buttons and IE6, it submits them all if you click one...