# Difference in button width between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, progressive-enhancement

I know there are lots of FF/Chrome CSS questions, but I can't seem to find this exact one.

Here is a JS Fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/G5rdD/1/

(Apologies for the long CSS, this was copied from the site.)

Essentially, Firefox and Chrome are giving me two different values for the inner most width of the button, 4 and 6. I'd like it to be 4 or less for both. What is causing this?

[image: From Chrome]

[image: From Firefox]

Comment: Can't you make a shorter, more concise demo? When asking questions on SO, it is considered polite to provide special demos (made from scratch), instead of just copy-pasting a large piece of code from your web-page.

Comment: You didn't specify a `width` other than `auto` nor a `max-width`, so the browser is allowed to make the element as wide as it likes to suit its developers' senses of style. Why not cap the width at `4px` if that's what you want?

Comment: If I did this, once the user rolls over the button, the button will only be 4 pixels wide (plus padding) try out the jsfiddle, you'll see it expands on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a `width` other than `auto`.

Different rendering engines think differently how websites should be rendered.

How about changing the `width` to `4px` and `:hover` to whatever you want?

Comment: Great minds think alike :) I just made this change and was about to post that it worked here when I saw your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the css below. Firefox add an extra padding at the button.

```
input::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Related: [Remove extra button spacing/padding in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox)

Source: http://wtfhtmlcss.com/#buttons-firefox-outline

Comment: I know it's old answer, but FF 41 and Chrome 47 not set same button height even with Your example. There is 2px differences... I have to add `margin-top:-1px; margin-bottom:-1px;` to fix this problem.