# make button and links height identical

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/blog/createEntry) there's a form with a Publish and Cancel button. The former is an `<input type="submit">` and the latter is an `<a>`. For some reason the Publish button is slightly taller than the Cancel button, though I don't understand why because they both have the same:

- font-size
- top and bottom border sizes
- top and bottom padding sizes

I had a look in Firebug and the reason for the difference seems to be because the `<input>` is given a `height` of 19px whereas the `<a>` has a height of 17px. How can I make the height of both identical?

### Update

I'm not bothered about supporting IE <= 7

Comment: You should post your code or a link to a pastebin version of the problem, so that future readers can follow the code discussed in this question. With 28k rep one could assume you'd be aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define height of your  `buttons`.

of Write like this:

```
a.primaryAction, .primaryAction.matchLink {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: height should not be used on buttons

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` was what helped me with this issue, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You should apply `display: inline-block` to the `a`, to match the button which already has `display: inline-block`.

You also need this to remove the [extra spacing in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox/5518143#5518143):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears that his site does not support IE7 anyway. I checked it in IE7, and there are worse problems than buttons with the wrong height. Anyway, `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1` [makes `inline-block` work in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575).

Comment: @cale_b there is an hack for inline-block for IE7

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem can be a real hassle to solve.

Only block elements accept a height.  You can use either `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to achieve this.

At first, `display:inline-block;` seems like it's a nice, easy way to go - but is not supported in IE7 or earlier.

So, you can either use inline-block and leave old browsers in the wake, or add a conditional stylesheet for ie7, or you can `display:block` and give them a width (if it's appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS rule would work in your case:

```
.buttonHolder * { height:17px; }
```