# Padding inside a button element not removable

Tags: html, css, button

On my *button* tag (note: not *input*), I put the character "X". It looks all-right-ish. However, when I add a border, I realize that the character isn't really centered. There seems to be some kind of padding **inside** the button.

Is that something that can be removed? If so, how?

I've tried to add styles (the usual *padding*, *margin*, *align* and *valign*) but it didn't got me anything useful.

The problem looks [like this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/xChDn/1/).

```
<button style='width:18px;height:18px;'>X</button>
```

Comment: The padding may be built right in to the font.

Comment: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/xChDn/ - there's no padding there

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: You may have to add `button::-moz-focus-inner { margin:0; padding:0}` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox

Comment: @Danield I'm getting the padding to appear as the jsFiddle in my edit shows. I took the liberty to add some thingies to your code. Kick me for forgetting to provide the jsFiddle in the first place, by the way. :)

Comment: @Ruben Yes, I can. It's in the edit. (Shamefully lowered head because I always forget that people can't see my screen... Sorry, hehe.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the fiddle, the button is not high enough for the text. But that is easily fixed by adding `line-height:0` to the CSS.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xChDn/2/).

Note that this does not influence the position of the "X" the same amount in different browsers. Alternative solutions might be to make the font size smaller, using a lowercase "x" or a multiplication sign "×" etc., or a combination.

By the way, you said you tried setting the margin, but that is never a solution. The margin is on the very outside of the button. Padding would work, but you can have only positive paddings, not negative.

Comment: It also seem to only affect the **vertical** alignment, not the **horizontal**. I guess I'll have to live with it.   :)

Answer (score 2):

My attempt at a solution:

I achieved a good result by overriding the default button border styling with my own styling, increasing the width and height by 1px, and specifying the `font-size`. I also added `<span>` tags around the button text to make it easier to style the actual text. *(I used `<span>` and then made it a block element, but `<p>` or `<div>` would have worked as well.)*

(My biggest question to you is "Why are you not styling the buttons yourself, and relying on ugly default button styles?".)

HTML:

```
<button><span class="text">X</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button span.text {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xChDn/8/)

Comment: Good question... Next question, please?   :)     Simply because I hoped that I didn't have to. Never needed it before. On the other hand, I never had buttons with "X" on. Good point at any measure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make a span tag inside button tag and then you can use any property`

HTML:

```
  <button type="button"><span class="buttonText">X</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
button{
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
}
.buttonText{
  color: blue,
  padding: 10px;
}
```