# Firefox button gets bigger

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, padding

I have a `button` and an `anchor tag` booth using the same class, but the button gets bigger for some reason. I found a question here already solved but it still is a little bit bigger than the other.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-actions">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Gravar</a></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Lixo</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-actions{
    float: right;
}

.item-actions ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.button {
    background: #3a9665;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2;
    -moz-border-radius: 2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px;
    border: solid #2d7a51 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #2d7a51;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Here I found a Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox/5518143#5518143) so I added this bit of CSS:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
```

But the result still isn't what I want, you will notice some difference in the following screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

**EDIT:**
I've removed `i tags` and the problem still exists, so thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recreate the issue on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with FireFox version 32.0.2. Adding `line-height: 1em;` to `.button` seems to work when I test it in FireFox:

```
.button {
    background: #3a9665;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a9665, #2d7a51);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2;
    -moz-border-radius: 2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px;
    border: solid #2d7a51 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I believe the issue’s cause comes from `<button type="submit" class="button">` tag having explicit styling while your `<a href="#" class="button">` doesn’t:

```
<div class="item-actions">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Gravar</a></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Lixo</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also could be caused by the use of explicit pixel sizing in `.button` with `font-size: 12px;`. I would recommend using another scheme for sizing such as `em`’s or even percentages.

Comment: I used em on font-size, like font-size:0.8em and the problem persisted, should I try in every value in pixels to convert to em?

Answer (score 1):

try to set the line-height of icons to 1:

```
.fa {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Still the same. But nice try