# Buttons in Firefox

Tags: firefox, button

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24hzd6fr/) — just open it in Chrome and Firefox, all latest.

There is *.button* class in my CSS — I use it for all kind of buttons: *a.button*, *button.button*, etc.

As you see, there are no difference in Chrome between *button.button* and any other **.button* elements.
As you see in FF — *button.button* is slightly bigger than any other **.buttons*.

How can I made FF to render any buttons properly, like Chrome do?

**UPDATE:**
This is absolutely not a duplicate of any post on SO.

StackOverflow asks for a code:

```css
.button {
    font: normal 100% Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #00f;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    border-radius: 3px;
    user-select: none;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button_medium {
    padding: 0 12px;
}

.button__text {
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button__text_medium {
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding:5em;">
    <button class="button button_medium" type="button">
        <span class="button__text button__text_medium">Save</span>
    </button>

    <label class="button button_medium">
        <span class="button__text button__text_medium">Save</span>
    </label>

    <span class="button button_medium">
        <span class="button__text button__text_medium">Save</span>
    </span>

    <a class="button button_medium">
        <span class="button__text button__text_medium">Save</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove extra button spacing/padding in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox)

Comment: No, this is absolutely not a duplicate — just open your link an read what is written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried? AFAIK it is really a duplicate. See also: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/button-padding-issue/

The following code will fix your issue:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
padding: 0 !important;
border: 0 none !important;
}
```

Comment: OMG, I really have tried to put &::-moz-focus-inner {...} in .button classes and it does not worked for me in SASS with Autoprefixer. So, it seems Autoprefixer have cut -moz rule. Aaaargh!