# Not able to get the same font displayed the same in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I could nee some help. I'm trying to get my page display the same in Firefox as in Chrome. The page using a imported font from Google and I'm not able to force it to look like the same.

[Left is Google Chrome and right (how it is supposed to be) Firefox](http://puu.sh/h03Qs/d86757f4ca.jpg)
[image]

And I have no idea now to fix it.
The affected CSS:

```
#big_header{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom:30px ;
    background-color: #858585;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: exocet;
    font-size: 8em;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #666666, 0 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#big_header::first-line{
    font-size: 180%;
}
```

And here the used Google Font:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I hope that some of you could help me :)

Comment: Are some of those things `<button>`s? If so, Firefox has more spacing inside them than other browsers. You can remove the extra space though; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox

Comment: @MrLister sadly not :/ but maybe I can handle this problem with the -moz rules ... mhh I will see when I'm back.