# CSS Text Colour

Tags: css

I have some text that I rotate and fade in. My problem is the text has no colour, and I would like to make it blue.

As you can see, I do assign a `color` attribute to the `rubber` class, but it does not seem to be taking effect.

Please can anyone advise how I can change my css to achieve this? Thank you

```css
.rubber {
  padding: 5px 2px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 155px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
// fade-in
 .fade-in p {
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadein 8s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 8s;
  /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rubber fade-in">
  <p>Job Offered</p>
</div>
```

Comment: do the rest of the commands work?

Comment: Your code is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ntp7pdwc/

Comment: @pokeyOne, thanks, Yes the rest of the commands work.

Comment: @Justinas, thanks, I see it does work in jsfiddle. Perhaps some other element above this affecting it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Check the steps in my answer here to easily debug this kind of problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462112/button-size-inheritance-mystery/40462301#40462301

Comment: The exact same code seems to work on my machine, using chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace `// fade-in` with `/* fade-in */` . In css
to add comment line you should use `/* comment here */`

Here is the working code

```css
.rubber {
  padding: 5px 2px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 155px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
/* fade in */
.fade-in  p{
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 8s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 8s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 8s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 8s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0.8;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0.8;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0.8;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0.8;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rubber fade-in"><p>Job Offered</p></div>
```

Comment: thank you. I think my problem is with some other element in the DOM affecting it. I have tried this with now success though: `color: blue !important;`

Comment: Apologies, I needed to reload. `!important` did work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in jsfiddle as well as it normal HTML page.
Only problem was with the comment in css style tag use this format

/ Shift+8 comment Shift+8/

Comment: Please proof-read your post.

Comment: Please update your answer. Syntax for css comment is not /comment/ right way is /*comment*/